# Aggregation of parallel for does not capture all iterations

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, locking

I have code that works great using a simple For loop, but I'm trying to speed it up.  I'm trying to adapt the code to use multiple cores and landed on Parallel For.

At a high level, I'm collecting the results from CalcRoutine for several thousand accounts and storing the results in an array with 6 elements.  I'm then re-running this process 1,000 times.  The order of the elements within each 6 element array is important, but the order for the final 1,000 iterations of these 6 element arrays is not important.  When I run the code using a For loop, I get a 6,000 element long list.  However, when I try the Parallel For version, I'm getting something closer to 600.  I've confirmed that the line "return localResults" gets called 1,000 times, but for some reason not all 6 element arrays get added to the list TotalResults.  Any insight as to why this isn't working would be greatly appreciated.

```
object locker = new object();

Parallel.For(0, iScenarios, () => new double[6], (int k, ParallelLoopState state, double[] localResults) =>
            {
                List<double> CalcResults = new List<double>();
                for (int n = iStart; n < iEnd; n++)
                {
                    CalcResults.AddRange(CalcRoutine(n, k));
                }
                localResults = this.SumOfResults(CalcResults);
                return localResults;                   
            },
             (double[] localResults) =>
             {                    
                 lock (locker)
                {
                     TotalResults.AddRange(localResults);
                 }
             });
```

EDIT:  Here's the "non parallel" version:

```
for (int k = 0; k < iScenarios; k++)            
{
          CalcResults.Clear();                
          for (int n = iStart; n < iEnd; n++)                
          {
              CalcResults.AddRange(CalcRoutine(n, k));                    
          }             
          TotalResults.AddRange(SumOfResults(CalcResults));
 }
```

The output for 1 scenario is a list of 6 doubles, 2 scenarios is a list of 12 doubles, ... n scenarios 6n doubles.

Also per one of the questions, I checked the number of times "TotalResults.AddRange..." gets called, and it's not the full 1,000 times.  Why wouldn't this be called each time?  With the lock, shouldn't each thread wait for this section to become available?

Comment: could you show the "non parallel" version?

Also, could you show an output on a smaller set of data for both types?

Comment: did you confirm that TotalResults.AddRange(localResults);
 gets called 1000 times as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the documentation for [`Parallel.For`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782936%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> These initial states are passed to the first *body* invocations on each task. Then, every subsequent *body* invocation returns a possibly modified state value that is passed to the next *body* invocation. Finally, the last *body* invocation on each task returns a state value that is passed to the *localFinally* delegate

But your *body* delegate is ignoring the *incoming* value of `localResults` which the previous iteration within this task returned. Having the loop state being an array makes it tricky to write a correct version. This will work but looks messy:

```
//EDIT - Create an array of length 0 here    V    for input to first iteration
Parallel.For(0, iScenarios, () => new double[0],
    (int k, ParallelLoopState state, double[] localResults) =>
        {
            List<double> CalcResults = new List<double>();
            for (int n = iStart; n < iEnd; n++)
            {
                CalcResults.AddRange(CalcRoutine(n, k));
            }
            localResults = localResults.Concat(
                               this.SumOfResults(CalcResults)
                           ).ToArray();
            return localResults;                   
        },
         (double[] localResults) =>
         {                    
             lock (locker)
            {
                 TotalResults.AddRange(localResults);
             }
         });
```

(Assuming Linq's enumerable extensions are in scope, for [`Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

I'd suggest using a different data structure (e.g. a `List<double>` rather than `double[]`) for the state that more naturally allows more elements to be added to it - but that would mean changing `SumOfResults` that you've not shown. Or just keep it all a bit more abstract:

```
Parallel.For(0, iScenarios, Enumerable.Empty<double>(),
    (int k, ParallelLoopState state, IEnumerable<double> localResults) =>
    {
        List<double> CalcResults = new List<double>();
        for (int n = iStart; n < iEnd; n++)
        {
            CalcResults.AddRange(CalcRoutine(n, k));
        }
        return localResults.Concat(this.SumOfResults(CalcResults));                   
    },
     (IEnumerable<double> localResults) =>
     {                    
         lock (locker)
        {
             TotalResults.AddRange(localResults);
         }
     });
```

---

(If it had worked the way you seem to have assumed, why would they have you provide two separate delegates, if all it did, on the return from *body*, was to immediately invoke *localFinally* with the return value?)

Comment: The second version worked beautifully. Can you help me understand why the first version created outputs of length ~ 6,648 instead of 6,000? The extra 648 values are all equal to 0 (e.g. 108 strings of <0,0,0,0,0,0>). Also the runtime for the first version is about 60% longer than the second.

Comment: @BikeSkiBikeSki - have you seen the edit where I changed the *localInit* function from `()=>new double[6]` to `()=>new double[0]` because I realised that that was going to add a set of 6 doubles all set to zero for each parallel task?

Comment: @BikeSkiBikeSki - re: the runtime - not unexpected. Because in the first version we spend a lot of time creating bigger and bigger arrays and copying all of the data into them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var iScenarios = 6;
        var iStart = 0;
        var iEnd = 1000;
        var totalResults = new List<double>();

        Parallel.For(0, iScenarios, k => {
            List<double> calcResults = new List<double>();
            for (int n = iStart; n < iEnd; n++)
                calcResults.AddRange(CalcRoutine(n, k));
            lock (totalResults)
            {
                totalResults.AddRange(calcResults);
            }
        });           

    }

    static IEnumerable<double> CalcRoutine(int a, int b)
    {
        yield return 0;
    }

    static double[] SumOfResults(IEnumerable<double> source)
    {
        return source.ToArray();
    }
}
```